# How to scale up parallel consumers in microservices

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, apache-kafka, microservices, scaling

For a new project we are looking at using Microservices together with RabbitMQ or Kafka. For both technologies I have the same question, the answer might however differ.

Consider three events:

1. Create product 1
2. Create profile 1
3. Delete product 1

We want to use these events to "duplicate" data among services. When using one consumer, all messages will be executed in the correct order and the database will be consistent.

However, when this one consumer gets to slow at processing the messages, one might want to add another consumer in parallel. At this point it is uncertain that event 1 is executed before event 3, which  may lead to an inconsistent database (delete first, create after).

Found some information [here](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-evaluation-disruptor-with-parallel-con) about the subject but both solution seem hard to implement. How would it be possible to scale up these consumers? Is there any difference in how one would handle this using RabbitMQ or Kafka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Kafka-based implementation, you just need to make sure that all events belonging to same "logical group" (id?) are landing at the same partition - in this case you can add more consumers (up to number of partitions) to handle events in parallel, but every consumer will handle events only for their logical group(s).

You can achieve this behavior by selecting correct key/partitioning approach - either use ID as a key, or come with more sophisticated partitioning implementation.

Comment: To expand on this you'd have to implement your own partioner class (https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Partitioner.html) and there are some gotchas with handling your own partition keys in Kafka. If for whatever one "logical group" is much higher volume than others, it's partition could outscale other partitions and require special maintenance to stay part of the same topic.

Comment: So in RabbitMQ you would just create queues for messages that can be handled concurrently I suppose

Answer (score 0):

> However, when this one consumer gets to slow at processing the messages, one might want to add another consumer in parallel.

[Parallel Consumer](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (PC) directly solves for this, by sub partitioning the input partitions by key and processing each key in parallel.

This solves the "[head of line blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-of-line_blocking)" problem you're describing.

It also tracks per record acknowledgement, among other things. Check out [Parallel Consumer on GitHub](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (it's open source BTW, and I'm the author).